# parallel requests to node.js, connect-mongo, session overwritten

Tags: session, mongodb, node.js, parallel-processing, express

In a current project (kind of a shop system), I use node.js with **expressJS** and **connect-mongo** as session store. On client side, I use a single request at startup to create a new session and send multiple parallel requests to the node.js server afterwards.
Because these parallel requests change the session, those changes seem to overwrite each other, although they change different objects of the session, of course.

Example (all 3 requests start at the same time):

- Request A pushes some products to the array `req.session.productHist['abc']`
- Request B pushes products to `req.session.productHist['def']`
- Request C takes some time, but doesn't change the session

Because request C finishes after request A and B, but starts before they finished, it seems to overwrite `session.productHist` with the value it held when request C started (null).

How can I fix this?

**Update:**

Some example code with console output:

```
var url = require('url'),
    express = require('express'),
    MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');

var aDay = 24*60*60*1000;

var app = express.createServer();

app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({
    secret: "secret",
    store: new MongoStore({ db: 'lmsCache' }),
    maxAge: aDay
    })
  );
  app.use(express.methodOverride());    app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.logger());
});


function sendStringified(req, res, data) {
    data = JSON.stringify(data);
    if (req.url_query.callback) { data = req.url_query.callback + "(" + data + ");"; }
    res.send(data);
}

function parseParams(req,res,next) {
  req.url_query = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
  next();
}

function doExpensiveStuff(req,res,next) {
  console.log("######################### init start");
  [...]
}


app.get('/init', parseParams, doExpensiveStuff, function(req,res) {
  console.log("init: session.productHist: " + JSON.stringify(req.session.productHist));
  console.log("######################### init end");
  sendStringified(req,res,null);
});


app.get('/products', parseParams, function(req,res) {

  console.log("######################### products "+req.url_query.category+" start");

  if(!req.session.productHist[req.url_query.category])
    req.session.productHist[req.url_query.category] = [];

  for(var i=0;i<2;i++) {
      req.session.productHist[req.url_query.category].push({ "id": new Date().toGMTString() }); 
  } 

  console.log("products: session.productHist: " + JSON.stringify(req.session.productHist));
  console.log("######################### products "+req.url_query.category+" end");
  sendStringified(req,res,[]);
});

app.get('/newSession', parseParams, function(req,res) {
  console.log("######################### newSession");
  req.session.productHist = {};
  sendStringified(req,res,true);
});  

app.listen(8080);  

time = new Date().toGMTString();  

console.log('Server starting at: ' + time);
```

Console log:

> Server starting at: Thu, 15 Dec 2011 15:50:37 GMT
>
> ################### newSession
>   
>   ################### init start
>   
>   ################### products -1 start
>
> products: session.productHist: {"-1":[{"id":"Thu, 15 Dec 2011 15:50:40 GMT"},{"id":"Thu, 15 Dec 2011 15:50:40 GMT"}]}
>
> ################### products -1 end
>
> init: session.productHist: {}
>
> ################### init end
>
> [...]
>
> ################### products -1 start
>
> products: session.productHist: {"-1":[{"id":"Thu, 15 Dec 2011 15:50:53 GMT"},{"id":"Thu, 15 Dec 2011 15:50:53 GMT"}]}
>
> ################### products -1 end

Comment: Can't request C occur after A & B?

Comment: i'd like to be able to send parallel requests if possible someway. i could send A&B after C finished, but that would slow down the user experience

Comment: What does request C do anyway..?

Comment: request C returns initialisation data such as user-data, categories to display etc. request A and B return products with different parameters (from different categories) and should add them to a product history so they won't be displayed again in later requests

Comment: You are most certainly doing something wrong. If you push to an array for example or define a different property on req.session it shouldn't get overridden.

Comment: I added some example code with console output to clearify things a bit. As you can see, the changes made in the first products call don't appear in the second dump of session.productsHist. I think connect-mongo stores the session as a json string which overwrites the complete old session data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have found the answer to this tricky problem.

From the [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#session-support) documentation:

`Properties on req.session are automatically saved on a response`

**Short version**

When you set a session variable (`req.session.my_var = value`), it's not actually saved then (at that exact moment), but later (when you send the response, in your case it's when you do `res.send`). That caused your problem.

**Long version**

So what does that mean exactly?

1. You make a request, then get the session variable (which is in state A) and after that do something with it (that requires some time)
2. You make another request and get the session variable (which is still in state A because the response hasn't been sent yet) and change some stuff to it
3. Now the session processing etc has been done so you send the response from 1), thus modifying the session variable and bringing it into state B
4. Here comes the 'fun' part, after you sent the response from 2). Now you aren't actually modifying the current session (which has been updated into state B), because the response was delayed, so what you're actually changing is the session from state A, bringing it into state C => which means all the modifications from state B were lost!

Comment: I think this is the problem, but do you have a solution for that? I guess I could mirror the whole session in the node.js memory but that's nothing I'd think about as a nice solution, as it would render the mongo storage unnecessary up to a certain point (and create a big overhead). I wondered if there were some ready-to-use solution to this since I'm certainly not the first one to stumble about that.

Comment: Not necessarily a perfect solution, but it's better to do your processing, then call `req.sessionStore.reload(callback_function)` and in the callback function to change the session and immediately call `res.send`. The best solution would be to have a communication channel (UNIX sockets, Redis) and to send a notification when you are changing the session (thus simulating a lock, ex of msg: 'session:id locked') and when you send the respond to trigger another message ('session:id unlocked'). Every req should be listening and not modifying the session if locked (on 'unlocked' reload session).

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I'll give that a try until I found a better solution (if I find one).