# Node/Express: concurrency issues when using session to store state

Tags: node.js, session, express, concurrency

So, I've searched quite a bit for this and found several somewhat similar questions, none of them really addressing the problem though so I thought this deserved a question of its own.

I have an express application with a bunch of routes that modify the session to keep state. Thing is, if there are multiple parallel requests, from time to time the session will be overwritten due to race conditions between requests.

So typically

```
...
app.use(express.static('/public'));
app.use(session(...));
app.route('methodA').get(function(req, res, next) {
    doSomethingSlow().then(function() {
        req.session.a = 'foo';
        res.send(...);
    }
});
app.route('methodB').get(function(req, res, next) {
    doSomethingElseSlow().then(function() {
        req.session.b = 'bar';
        res.send(...);
    }
});
```

Basically the problem is straightforward and is e.g. described  in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8523574) answer. Express stores the session in res.end(), but while a methodA request is being handled, a methodB request could have modified the session in the meantime so that when methodA stores the session it will overwrite any changes made by methodB. So even though node is single-threaded and all requests are served by the same thread we can end up with concurrency issues as soon as any method is doing something asynchronous thereby letting other requests be handled simultaneously.

However, I am struggling to decide how I should proceed to solve this problem. All answers I have found only list ways of *minimizing the probability* of this happening, e.g. by making sure static content does not store the session by registering the serve-static MW before the session MW. But this only helps to some extent; if there are in fact API methods that are supposed to be called in parallel some real concurrency approach to session updates is needed (IMO, when it comes to concurrency issues, every "solution" that strives to minimize the probability of problems occuring rather than addressing the actual problem is bound to go wrong).

Basically these are the alternatives I am exploring so far:

1. **Prevent parallel requests within the same session completely by modifying my client to make sure it calls all API methods serially.**

   This may be possible but will have quite some impact on my architecture and may impact performance. It also avoids the problem rather than solves it and if I make something wrong in my client or the API is used by another client I might still run into this randomly, so it doesn't feel very robust.
2. **Make sure each session write is preceded by a session reload and make the entire reload-modify-write operation atomic.**

   I am not sure how to achieve this. Even if I modify res.end() to reload the session *just* before modifying and storing it, because reading and writing the session is async I/O it seems possible that this could happen:

   - request A reloads the session
   - request A modifies session.A = 'foo'
   - request B reloads the session (and will not see session.A)
   - request A stores the session
   - request B modifies session.B = 'bar'
   - request B stores the session, overwriting previous store so that session.A is missing

So in essence I would need to make each reload-modify-store atomic, which basically means blocking the thread? Feels wrong, and I have no idea how to do it.

3. **Stop using the session in this way altogether and pass necessary state as params to each request or by some other means.**

   This also avoids the problem rather than addressing it. It would also have huge impact on my project. But sure, it might be the best way.
4. **???**

Anyone got any ideas how to address this in a robust way?
Thanks!

Comment: We had the same issue recently. Seems like that is just the nature of the beast and short of writing our own session manager or switching to something besides Redis we didn't come up with any better options. We wished we had done #3 from the outset but it was too expensive to switch to now. Our final solution was to reduce the number of requests that used session (we are using Sails which would do a get/set on session on every request). We had one object that all requests were filtered through before going to node so we modified it to queue requests (your option #1) and that worked well.

Comment: It is technically possible to do this with Redis using transactional updates (http://redis.io/topics/transactions) but you have to implement it yourself as it is not supported in connect-redis. It also might require changes in express-session. The problem with optimistic locking (as implemented in Redis) is that if an update fails due to concurrent updates, you have to reload the new state, replay your changes and write again.

Comment: You could just save session immediately with req.session.save() rather than wait for the res.end to do it

Comment: @Omiron how would that help? There is still no atomicity preventing two clients from doing load-modify-save simultaneously.

Comment: Ah true, for my use case this minimised the chances of it happening enough but you are right it is still possible

Comment: Like I said in the question, addressing concurrency problems by minimizing probabilities is bound to fail. Keeping your fingers crossed and hoping for the best doesn't help when a user profile is corrupted in production... But I appreciate your input.

Comment: I'm using a global boolean for each endpoint accessible concurrently and using recursive callbacks if the boolean is set to 'active' until its 'unactivated'

Comment: you can also use the node-mutex library if that helps

Comment: This seems like a job for a database rather than in-memory storage. Then you have control over when during request handling to load and save your data. And you can do things like "UPDATE some_table SET some_value = some_value + 10 WHERE id= 123" to make atomic changes that are aware of the current state without worrying about accidental overwrites. If this is frequently accessed data then chances are good the value will stay in the database server's memory rather than involving frequent file reads and writes, yielding high performance.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution to this is to create a simple middleware for express that will maintain a list of all current requests and queue any requests coming from the same session. It won't call next() until the previous requests for that session-id have been processed first.

Every time a request comes in it can store it in an object with the key being the session-id cookie name and the value an array of current requests for the session-id.

`{
  'session-id1': [... queued requests ...],
  'session-id2': ...
}`

When a request is completed it will remove it's self from the array and trigger the next request in the array to be processed.

You can also add a flag to each request in the header to allow for concurrent running for requests that don't need to be queued (they don't write to the session for example) thus improving performance when queueing is not needed.

You should be able to implement this without having to change your application. You could also change the opt-out option in the header to a opt-in option instead meaning it will just process all request concurrently like it would normally unless specified otherwise.

Comment: This becomes even more tricky if you have multiple node instances, with some db session store. In that case middleware keeping any queue in memory won't fix the problem. The middlewares across node instances should also get in sync via some db, which makes the overall architecture yet more complex :-(

Comment: @TMG you are totally right about that this is pretty useless on a real life scenario unless you have a very small application. Using a central db to store your list such as mongo could be used instead to make it work in combination with $addToSet and $pull while doing a findAndModify. As you say it's not an easy thing to implement properly.

Comment: Yeah this is a pretty nice approach for a small app, such as something running locally on an intranet etc, but like argued above, it won't scale. Any solution that depends on having a single instance is bound to give you problems.